# Is it possible to disable the auto acknowledge of createQueueBrowser of jms?

Tags: java, azure, jms

i am iterating all the message of queue using createQueueBrowser, it is removing all the messages from queue once it reads,i want to iterate through all the messages without deleting in the queue. how to do it?

```
    public class Receive {
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = null;
        Connection connection = null;

        void receivemsg() throws JMSException {
            connectionFactory = new JmsConnectionFactory("RootManageSharedAccessKey",
                    "Gkt0Egjp/5YTrqAf9z+f2+HoRungEOh4OMSRA69js6M=",
                    "amqps://amqpqpid.servicebus.windows.net?amqp.idleTimeout=-1");

            /*
             * connectionFactory = new
             * JmsConnectionFactory("RootManageSharedAccessKey",
             * "Gkt0Egjp/5YTrqAf9z+f2+HoRungEOh4OMSRA69js6M=",
             * "amqps://amqpqpid.servicebus.windows.net?amqp.idleTimeout=-1");
             */

            connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            connection.start();
            System.out.println("Receiving messages...");
            Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            Destination replyQueue = session.createQueue("ackqueue");
            //MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(replyQueue);
            TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();
            Queue recieve = session.createQueue("requestor");

            QueueBrowser browser = session.createBrowser(recieve);

            Enumeration msgs = browser.getEnumeration();


            if (!msgs.hasMoreElements()) {
                System.out.println("No messages in queue");
            } else {

                while (msgs.hasMoreElements()) {
                    Message tempMsg = (Message) msgs.nextElement();

                    System.out.println("Message: " + tempMsg.getJMSCorrelationID());
                    if(tempMsg.getJMSCorrelationID().equalsIgnoreCase("helloworld"))
                    {

                        System.out.println("matched and acked");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }


        }

        public static void main(String args[]) throws JMSException {

            Receive receiver = new Receive();

            receiver.receivemsg();

            System.out.println("Received Messages");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am surprised a queue browser removing messages from queue. A JMS Queue Browser is meant for the specific purpose of browsing messages in a queue and not remove. Messaging provider libraries which claim JMS compliance must implement this. I guess this is an issue with Azure JMS implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed the documents of Apache Qpid, there is not any method or option to support consumers to be non-destructive within the AMQP client. The only way for Qpid is force set `true` for [`qpid.ensure_nondestructive_consumers`](http://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-java-6.1.2/java-broker/book/Java-Broker-Concepts-Queues.html#Java-Broker-Concepts-Queue-EnsureNonDestructiveConsumers) option for Qpid broker server-side, but it's not suitable for your current scenario `Azure Service Bus Queue`.

On Azure Service Bus Queue, there is a REST API [`Peek-Lock Message (Non-Destructive Read)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/peek-lock-message-non-destructive-read) which can satisfy your needs. So you can refer to the section [`Receive messages from a queue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-java-how-to-use-queues#receive-messages-from-a-queue) of offical tutorial for Service Bus Queue to use [Azure Java SDK for Service Bus](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-servicebus) to set [`ReceiveMode.PEEK_LOCK`](http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/windowsazure/services/servicebus/models/ReceiveMode.html) in the code below to do it.

```
ReceiveMessageOptions opts = ReceiveMessageOptions.DEFAULT;
opts.setReceiveMode(ReceiveMode.PEEK_LOCK);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Peter we are not supposed to use azure java sdk without this we should be able to achieve this